# I have a problem with C code and i cant see the mistake. Its a simple program

Tags: c

I am a beginner in programming. For enviroment I am using Windows PowerShell ISE. I get a strange error and I dont know where could be the problem.

This is the code I am using:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(Int argc, char **argv){

int n;
printf ("Enter a number: ");

int seconds = (n % 60);
int minutes = (n % 3600) / 60;
int hours = (n % 86400) / 3600;
int days = (n % (86400 * 30)) / 86400;

printf ("Pretvorjeno število v sekunde, minute, ure ter dneve: ");
printf (%d +" dni "+ %d +" ur "+ %d +" minut in "+ %d +" sekund", days, hours, minutes, seconds);
}
```

The error i get:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tE5NZ.png)

Comment: Change `Int argc` to `int argc`. C is case-sensistive.

Comment: You need to read `printf` documentation as of now you are abusing it.

Comment: so where is the n initialized

Comment: and where is the number entered?

Comment: and the last printf should be printf ("%d  dni  %d  ur  %d  minut in  %d sekund", days, hours, minutes, seconds);

Answer (score 1):

Your first error is coming from what you wrote inside the main method

```c
int main(){
```

You need for the user to enter the input, the program doesn't know what is n.

```c
int n;
printf ("Enter a number: ");
scanf_s("%d", &n);
```

at your final line you need to change it to

```c
printf ("%d dni %d ur %d minut in %d sekund", days, hours, minutes, seconds);
```

Answer (score 1):

from

```
int main(Int argc, char **argv){
```

to

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
```

from

```
printf (%d +" dni "+ %d +" ur "+ %d +" minut in "+ %d +" sekund", days, hours, minutes, seconds);
```

to

```
printf ("%d dni %d ur %d minut in %d sekund", days, hours, minutes, seconds);
```

Read, read, read. Documentation is very important. Here is a beginner friendly [site](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm).

Comment: That was a mistake yes. And before you asked me if I am sure that im compiling for c. The program makes an automatic .c extension for the file, so I assume that this actually is C :D
I made another comment under the first answer with even more errors :O

Answer (score 0):

Corrected version :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int n;
  printf ("Enter a number: ");

  if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
    int seconds = (n % 60);
    int minutes = (n % 3600) / 60;
    int hours = (n % 86400) / 3600;
    int days = (n % (86400 * 30)) / 86400;

    printf ("Pretvorjeno število v sekunde, minute, ure ter dneve: ");
    printf ("%d dni %d ur %d minut in %d sekund", days, hours, minutes, seconds);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I removed argc/argv because there are not used

I added a *scanf* to read the number and of course check if the read success (to check if the number is positive can be interesting too)

I added a newline in the printf and corrected the format

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter a number: 12345678
Pretvorjeno število v sekunde, minute, ure ter dneve: 22 dni 21 ur 21 minut in 18 sekund
```

Comment: @Matic1295 are you sure you compiled in C ?

Comment: The fact that your screenshots show that you're running it as a `.ps1` file is worrying

Comment: @Matic1295 online compiling / execution : https://onlinegdb.com/Hy66syB5N

Comment: @bruno thank you very much for the online solution. It will work for me for now. 
But I still dont understand why. Even if I go manual(trough the PowerShell) to execute the file its the same.

Comment: @Matic1295 I don't think that Windows PowerShell Integrated Scripting Environment (ISE) qualifies as a C compiler.

Comment: I'm not familiar with powershell but from the screenshots it seemed like it was trying to interpret the c instructions as a powershell script. You might want to look into using a c compiler and running the program through powershell instead.